# Pointer initialization in C

Tags: c

In C why is it legal to do

```
char * str = "Hello";
```

but illegal to do

```
int * arr = {0,1,2,3};
```

Comment: Cause, that ain't an array. (The standard doesn't specify that to work.)

Comment: Because we usually expect `printf("Hello, world!\n");` to work without any variables, but no one wants to use `memcpy(arr, {0,1,2,3}, sizeof arr);`

Comment: @ChrisLutz: Who says no one wants to?  We don't use it because the language doesn't support it; the (reasonable IMHO) question is *why*.

Comment: @KeithThonpson - As I was writing that I thought, "you know, this might be kind of useful at some point", but then cnicutar's answer reminded me that we _could_ actually do that (albeit with slightly longer syntax).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess that's just how initializers work in C. However, you can do:

```
int *v = (int[]){1, 2, 3}; /* C99. */
```

Comment: You can do the same syntax for strings to get a modifiable string "literal".

Answer (score 8):

As for C89:

`"A string"`, when used outside `char` array initialization, is a *string literal*; the standard says that when you use a string literal it's as if you created a global `char` array initialized to that value and wrote its name instead of the literal (there's also the additional restriction that any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior). In your code you are initializing a `char *` with a string literal, which decays to a `char` pointer and everything works fine.

However, if you use a string literal to initialize a `char` array, several magic rules get in action, so it is no longer "as if an array ... etc" (which would not work in array initialization), but it's just a nice way to tell the compiler how the array should be initialized.

The `{1, 2, 3}` way to initialize arrays keeps just this semantic: it's only for initialization of array, it's not an "array literal".

Answer (score 5):

In the case of:

```
char * str = "Hello";
```

`"Hello"` is a string literal.  It's loaded into memory (but often read-only) when the program is run, and has a memory address that can be assigned to a pointer like `char *str`.  String literals like this are an exception, though.

With:

```
int * arr = {0,1,2,3};
```

..you're effectively trying to point at an array that hasn't been put anywhere in particular in memory.  `arr` is a pointer, not an array; it holds a memory address, but does not itself have storage for the array data.  If you use `int arr[]` instead of `int *arr`, then it works, because an array like that is associated with storage for its contents.  Though the array decays to a pointer to its data in many contexts, it's not the same thing.

Even with string literals, `char *str = "Hello";` and `char str[] = "Hello";` do different things.  The first sets the pointer `str` to point at the string literal, and the second initializes the array `str` with the values from `"Hello"`.  The array has storage for its data associated with it, but the pointer just points at data that happens to be loaded into memory somewhere already.

Answer (score 3):

Because there's no point in declaring and initializing a pointer to an int array, when the *array name* can be used as a pointer to the first element. After

```
int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
```

you can use `arr` like an `int *` in almost all contexts (the exception being as operand to `sizeof`).

Comment: The other exception being as the operand of the unary `&` address operator; `&arr` yields the address of the array, not of its first element (same memory location, different type).

Answer (score 2):

... or you can abuse the string literals and store the numbers as a string literal, which for a little endian machine will look as follows:

```
int * arr = (int *)"\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\3\0\0\0";
```

Comment: A little endian machine, where `sizeof int` is 4, to be precise.